# Slack channel membership of a user

Tags: slack, slack-api

I was wondering if there is any possibility to find what channels is certain user part of. We are on a Business+ plan and I know something like this is possible in Enterprise Grid but I thought if there is any API method that could help me with that even on our plan.

Thank you in advance for all the ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://api.slack.com/methods/users.conversations API

This API provides list of conversations the calling user may access.

You'll need to provide `user` argument: 
 *It allows browsing conversations by a specific user ID's membership.*
 ***Non-public channels are restricted to those where the calling user shares membership.***